# Getting an exception as "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n" while moving file

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

I have written a code to move a file as follows

```
            private void Move_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strOrgpath = string.Empty, strNewpath = string.Empty;
        strOrgpath = tvwACH.SelectedNode.ToString();
        string strPath = strOrgpath.Substring(10);
        FolderBrowserDialog folderborwser1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();

       if (folderborwser1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                strNewpath = folderborwser1.SelectedPath;
                File.Move(strPath, strNewpath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

But i am getting the exception as i mentioned can any one tell why and some times i am getting the error as access to the path is denied

Comment: Have you checked the values of strPath and strNewPath to make sure they look right on that File.Move? And can you give us examples of what those values might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your substring call returns the correct result. If possible, use static methods from the `Path` class instead. Take a look at the MSDN page for [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) and pay attention to what parameters are expected -- you should provide two valid full file names (e.g. `C:\Blah\myFile.txt`).

"Access denied" error message might happen if the user picks a folder they don't have write access to in the folder browser dialog. That's a scenario you'll have to handle in your code, perhaps by catching the `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Update: the destination file should also point to a filename. So you'll need to do something like this:

```
var origFileName = Path.GetFileName(strPath);
strNewpath = Path.Combine(folderborwser1.SelectedPath, origFileName);
File.Move(strPath, strNewpath);
```

Comment: My substring is returning correct result only i am getting the path as "c:\some.txt" and i would like to move this to some other destination selected by user from folderbrowserdialog

Comment: The destination for the move should also be a filename. I updated my answer to include some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the values that are being used in your application at run-time, I'm guessing `tvwACH.SelecteNode.ToString()` or `strOrgpath.Substring(10)` is not a valid File System path.

You should Debug your application and set a breakpoint to see what those values are (and post them if it's not obvious what your problem is at that point).

Comment: I am getting the values correctly. Initial path will be the treenode so i have taken the substring of that and assigned to another string

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error because i was trying to use one of this symbols in file name
of destination path '**\ / : * ? " < > |**'.